# Retrive location specific posts via application access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, geolocation

I have a webpage that retrieves facebook posts of a fan page.

The web-page does not require visitors to log in via FBConnect. Instead a Facebook application was created and an application secret was obtained via the following link : 
graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[APP_ID]&client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]&grant_type=client_credentials

I am thus able to retrieve posts from the fan page via code-behind(php/.net) with the above application's access_token using the following url :

graph.facebook.com/cocacola/posts?access_token=[APPLICATION_ACCESS_TOKEN]

Problem : I cannot find any location specific posts. By location specific posts, I mean posts that are visible only to people from specific countries.

Has anybody been able to achieve this?
Thanks